# Need run some jquery code between each step in a form wizard (see update 3)

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am adding to my spring project a form wizard based on bootstrap, where the view is this:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Instala&ccedil;&atilde;o da aplica&ccedil;&atilde;o</title>
</head>
<body>

<div id="pad-wrapper">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12 col-xs-12">
                    <div id="fuelux-wizard" class="wizard row">
                        <ul class="wizard-steps">
                            <li data-target="#step1" class="active">
                                <span class="step">1</span>
                                <span class="title">Banco de dados</span>
                            </li>
                            <li data-target="#step2">
                                <span class="step">2</span>
                                <span class="title">Dados do administrador</span>
                            </li>
                            <li data-target="#step3">
                                <span class="step">3</span>
                                <span class="title">Conclus&atilde;o</span>
                            </li>
                        </ul>                            
                    </div>
                    <div class="step-content">
                        <div class="step-pane active" id="step1">
                            <div class="row form-wrapper">
                                <div class="col-md-8">
                                    <form method="post" action="">
                                        <div class="field-box">
                                            <label>M&aacute;quina (IP):</label>
                                            <input class="form-control" type="text" />
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="field-box">
                                            <label>Usu&aacute;rio:</label>
                                            <input class="form-control" type="text" />
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="field-box">
                                            <label>Senha:</label>
                                            <input class="form-control" type="text" />
                                        </div>
                                    </form>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="step-pane" id="step2">
                            <div class="row form-wrapper">
                                <div class="col-md-8">
                                    <form>
                                        <div class="field-box">
                                            <label>Usu&aacute;rio:</label>
                                            <input class="form-control" type="text" />
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="field-box">
                                            <label>Digite uma senha:</label>
                                            <input class="form-control" type="password" />
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="field-box">
                                            <label>Repita a senha:</label>
                                            <input class="form-control" type="password" />
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="field-box">
                                            <label>E-mail:</label>
                                            <input class="form-control" type="text" />
                                        </div>
                                    </form>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="step-pane" id="step3">
                            <div class="row form-wrapper">
                                <div class="col-md-8">
                                    O sistema foi configurado com sucesso! Agora voc&ecirc; pode efetuar seu login e come&ccedil;ar a usa-lo.
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="wizard-actions">
                        <button type="button" disabled class="btn-glow primary btn-prev"> 
                            <i class="icon-chevron-left"></i> Pr&otilde;ximo
                        </button>
                        <button type="button" class="btn-glow primary btn-next" data-last="Finish">
                            Seguinte <i class="icon-chevron-right"></i>
                        </button>
                        <button type="button" class="btn-glow success btn-finish">
                            Fa&ccedil;a login no sistema!
                        </button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

</body>
</html>
```

I want that after each step, run one jquery function which will perform soe update in the server (first step should create a database, second step should create a user), but I have no idea how to do this. Anyone can point me a direction accomplish the result I expected?

**UPDATE**

Ok, then I made some changes in the html code, and include some jquery code, which I guess I think should do the job, but isn't working. Anyone can see what I am doing wrong?

```
<body>

    <!-- main container -->
    <div class="content">

<div id="pad-wrapper">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12 col-xs-12">
                    <div id="fuelux-wizard" class="wizard row">
                        <ul class="wizard-steps">
                            <li data-target="#step1" class="active">
                                <span class="step">1</span>
                                <span class="title">Banco de dados</span>
                            </li>
                            <li data-target="#step2">
                                <span class="step">2</span>
                                <span class="title">Dados do administrador</span>
                            </li>
                            <li data-target="#step3">
                                <span class="step">3</span>
                                <span class="title">Conclus&atilde;o</span>
                            </li>
                        </ul>                            
                    </div>
                    <div class="step-content">

                        <div class="step-pane active" id="step1">
                            <div class="row form-wrapper">
                                <div class="col-md-8">
                                    <form name="target" method="post" action="<c:out value="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/instala/createdb"/>">
                                        <div class="field-box">
                                            <label>M&aacute;quina (IP):</label>
                                            <input class="form-control" type="text" name="maquina" />
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="field-box">
                                            <label>Usu&aacute;rio:</label>
                                            <input class="form-control" type="text" name="usuario_db" />
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="field-box">
                                            <label>Senha:</label>
                                            <input class="form-control" type="text" name="senha_db" />
                                        </div>
                                    </form>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="step-pane" id="step2">
                            <div class="row form-wrapper">
                                <div class="col-md-8">
                                    <form name="target" method="post" action="<c:out value="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/instala/createuser"/>">
                                        <div class="field-box">
                                            <label>Usu&aacute;rio:</label>
                                            <input class="form-control" type="text" name="usuario" />
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="field-box">
                                            <label>Digite uma senha:</label>
                                            <input class="form-control" type="password" name="senha1" />
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="field-box">
                                            <label>Repita a senha:</label>
                                            <input class="form-control" type="password" name="senha2" />
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="field-box">
                                            <label>E-mail:</label>
                                            <input class="form-control" type="text" name="email" />
                                        </div>
                                    </form>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="step-pane" id="step3">
                            <div class="row form-wrapper payment-info">
                                <div class="col-md-8">
                                    O sistema foi configurado com sucesso! Agora voc&ecirc; pode efetuar seu login e come&ccedil;ar a usa-lo.
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                    </div>

                    <div class="wizard-actions">
                        <button type="button" disabled class="btn-glow primary btn-prev"> 
                            <i class="icon-chevron-left"></i> Anterior
                        </button>
                        <button type="submit" class="btn-glow primary btn-next" data-last="Finish">
                            Pr&otilde;ximo <i class="icon-chevron-right"></i>
                        </button>
                        <button type="button" onclick="<c:out value="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/acesso/login"/>" class="btn-glow success btn-finish">
                            Fa&ccedil;a login no sistema!
                        </button>
                    </div>

                    <div class="alert alert-danger" id="result">
                        <i class="icon-remove-sign"></i>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- end main container -->

    <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript
    ================================================== -->
    <!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
    <script src="<c:out value="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/jquery/js/jquery-2.1.0.min.js"/>"></script>
    <script src="<c:out value="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/jquery/js/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.min.js"/>"></script>
    <script src="<c:out value="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"/>"></script>
    <script src="<c:out value="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/extras/js/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.js"/>"></script>
    <script src="<c:out value="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/extras/js/jquery-ui-sliderAccess.js"/>"></script>
    <script src="<c:out value="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/extras/js/fuelux.wizard.js"/>"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $( "#result" ).hide();

            var $wizard = $('#fuelux-wizard'),
                $btnPrev = $('.wizard-actions .btn-prev'),
                $btnNext = $('.wizard-actions .btn-next'),
                $btnFinish = $(".wizard-actions .btn-finish");

            $wizard.wizard().on('finished', function(e) {
                // wizard complete code
            }).on("changed", function(e) {
                var step = $wizard.wizard("selectedItem");
                // reset states
                $btnNext.removeAttr("disabled");
                $btnPrev.removeAttr("disabled");
                $btnNext.show();
                $btnFinish.hide();

                if (step.step === 1) {
                    $btnPrev.attr("disabled", "disabled");
                    //
                } else if(step.step === 2) {
                    //
                } else if (step.step === 3) {
                    $btnNext.hide();
                    $btnFinish.show();
                };
            });

            $btnPrev.on('click', function() {
                $wizard.wizard('previous');
            });

            $btnNext.on('click', function() {
                $wizard.wizard('next');
            });

            $( "#target" ).submit(function( event ) {

              // Stop form from submitting normally
              event.preventDefault();

              // Get some values from elements on the page:
              var $form = $( this ),
                url = $form.attr( "action" );

              // Send the data using post
              var posting = $.post( url, $(this).serialize() );

              // Put the results in a div
              posting.done(function( data ) {
                  if(data == "not") {
                    $( "#result" ).show();
                    $( "#result" ).empty().append( "Erro ao executar os procedimentos dessa etapa" ).fadeOut();
                  }

                  $("#target").each (function(){
                      this.reset();
                  });
              });
            });
        });
    </script>

</body>
```

**UPDATE 2**

My current jquery code is this:

```
    $(function () {
        $( "#result" ).hide();

        var $wizard = $('#fuelux-wizard'),
            $btnPrev = $('.wizard-actions .btn-prev'),
            $btnNext = $('.wizard-actions .btn-next'),
            $btnFinish = $(".wizard-actions .btn-finish");

        $wizard.wizard().on("finished", function(e) {
            alert("finished");
            var fnprocessform = function (targetform) {
                if (targetform.attr('id') === 'target') { 
                    alert('validating form 1');

                    var maquina = $("input[maquina]").val();
                    var usuario = $("input[usuario_db]").val();
                    var senha = $("input[senha_db]").val();

                    var request = $.ajax({
                      url: "<c:out value="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/instala/createdb"/>",
                      type: "POST",
                      data: { maquina : maquina, usuario_db: usuario, senha_db: senha }
                    });
                    return request;
                }
                if (targetform.attr('id') === 'target2') {
                    alert('validating form 2');

                    var usuario = $("input[usuario]").val();
                    var senha = $("input[senha1]").val();
                    var pnome = $("input[primeiroNome]").val();
                    var unome = $("input[ultimoNome]").val();

                    var request = $.ajax({
                          url: "<c:out value="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/instala/createuser"/>",
                          type: "POST",
                          data: { usuario : usuario, senha1: senha, primeiroNome: pnome, ultimoNome: unome }
                    });
                    return request;
                };
            };
            if(fnprocessform == "yes") {
                alert('form validated');
                var nextstep = $('.wizard-steps').find('.active').next();
                nextstep.find('a').tab('show');
            }
        }).on("changed", function(e) {
            alert("changed");
            var step = $wizard.wizard("selectedItem");
            $btnNext.removeAttr("disabled");
            $btnPrev.removeAttr("disabled");
            $btnNext.show();
            $btnFinish.hide();

            if (step.step === 1) {
                $btnPrev.attr("disabled", "disabled");
            } else if (step.step === 3) {
                $btnNext.hide();
                $btnFinish.show();
            };
        });

        $btnPrev.on('click', function() {
            $wizard.wizard('previous');
        });

        $btnNext.on('click', function() {
            $wizard.wizard('next');
        });

    });
```

My problem now is that, otherwise from event "clicked", the event "finished" is never triggered when I access the page (it supposed to be triggered when I click in the button "next").

Anyone can tell me what's wrong with my current approach?

**UPDATE 3**

Ok, after a contact with the creator of bootstrap theme I using, I learn the event "finished" is only triggered in the end of the wizard. What I want is run some jquery code after first step (to create an database in server) and after second step (to create an user in the database). After the third step, I just go to login page.

My current HTML code is this:

```
<!-- main container -->
<div class="content">

<div id="pad-wrapper">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12 col-xs-12">
                <div id="fuelux-wizard" class="wizard row">
                    <ul class="wizard-steps">
                        <li data-target="#step1" class="active">
                            <span class="step">1</span>
                            <span class="title">Banco de dados</span>
                        </li>
                        <li data-target="#step2">
                            <span class="step">2</span>
                            <span class="title">Dados do administrador</span>
                        </li>
                        <li data-target="#step3">
                            <span class="step">3</span>
                            <span class="title">Conclus&atilde;o</span>
                        </li>
                    </ul>                            
                </div>
                <div class="step-content">

                    <div class="step-pane active" id="step1">
                        <div class="row form-wrapper">
                            <div class="col-md-8">
                                <form id="target">
                                    <div class="field-box">
                                        <label>M&aacute;quina (IP):</label>
                                        <input class="form-control" type="text" name="maquina" />
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="field-box">
                                        <label>Usu&aacute;rio:</label>
                                        <input class="form-control" type="text" name="usuario_db" />
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="field-box">
                                        <label>Senha:</label>
                                        <input class="form-control" type="text" name="senha_db" />
                                    </div>
                                </form>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="step-pane" id="step2">
                        <div class="row form-wrapper">
                            <div class="col-md-8">
                                <form id="target2">
                                    <div class="field-box">
                                        <label>Usu&aacute;rio:</label>
                                        <input class="form-control" type="text" name="usuario" />
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="field-box">
                                        <label>Digite uma senha:</label>
                                        <input class="form-control" type="password" name="senha1" />
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="field-box">
                                        <label>Repita a senha:</label>
                                        <input class="form-control" type="password" name="senha2" />
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="field-box">
                                        <label>Primeiro nome:</label>
                                        <input class="form-control" type="text" name="primeiroNome" />
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="field-box">
                                        <label>Ultimo nome:</label>
                                        <input class="form-control" type="text" name="ultimoNome" />
                                    </div>
                                </form>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="step-pane" id="step3">
                        <div class="row form-wrapper payment-info">
                            <div class="col-md-8">
                                O sistema foi configurado com sucesso! Agora voc&ecirc; pode efetuar seu login e come&ccedil;ar a usa-lo.
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>

                <div class="wizard-actions">
                    <button type="button" disabled class="btn-glow primary btn-prev"> 
                        <i class="icon-chevron-left"></i> Anterior
                    </button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn-glow primary btn-next" data-last="Finish">
                        Pr&otilde;ximo <i class="icon-chevron-right"></i>
                    </button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn-glow success btn-finish">
                        Fa&ccedil;a login no sistema!
                    </button>
                </div>

                <div class="alert alert-danger" id="result">
                    <i class="icon-remove-sign"></i>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- end main container -->
```

My  current jquery code is this:

```
    $(function () {
        $( "#result" ).hide();

        var $wizard = $('#fuelux-wizard'),
            $btnPrev = $('.wizard-actions .btn-prev'),
            $btnNext = $('.wizard-actions .btn-next'),
            $btnFinish = $(".wizard-actions .btn-finish");

        $wizard.wizard().on("finished", function(e) {
            //
        }).on("changed", function(e) {
            var step = $wizard.wizard("selectedItem");
            $btnNext.removeAttr("disabled");
            $btnPrev.removeAttr("disabled");
            $btnNext.show();
            $btnFinish.hide();

            if (step.step === 1) {
                $btnPrev.attr("disabled", "disabled");
            } else if (step.step === 3) {
                $btnNext.hide();
                $btnFinish.show();
            };
        });

        $btnPrev.on('click', function() {
            $wizard.wizard('previous');
        });

        $btnNext.on('click', function() {
            $wizard.wizard('next');
        });

    });
```

My idea is add a new block

```
.on("--event--", function(e) {
```

but I don't know which event is triggered between each step (if any). Anyone have sugestions?

Comment: Attach event handlers to any buttons that trigger your different "steps". As it stands example doesn't show any effort in this area or really explain what specific problem you are having in implementing this.

Comment: My problem is that the set of buttons of the wizard is unique to all the steps (placed in the end of the page). Which element should trigger the handler in this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, then I finally solved this question after more tryouts. That's the final code:

```
    $(function () {
        $( "#result" ).hide();

        var $wizard = $('#fuelux-wizard'),
            $btnPrev = $('.wizard-actions .btn-prev'),
            $btnNext = $('.wizard-actions .btn-next'),
            $btnFinish = $(".wizard-actions .btn-finish");

        $wizard.wizard().on("finished", function(e) {
            //
        }).on("changed", function(e) {
            var step = $wizard.wizard("selectedItem");
            $btnNext.removeAttr("disabled");
            $btnPrev.removeAttr("disabled");
            $btnNext.show();
            $btnFinish.hide();

            if (step.step === 1) {
                $btnPrev.attr("disabled", "disabled");
            } else if (step.step === 3) {
                $btnNext.hide();
                $btnFinish.show();
            };
        });

        $btnPrev.on('click', function() {
            $wizard.wizard('previous');
        });

        $btnNext.on('click', function() {
            var step = $wizard.wizard("selectedItem");
            if(step.step === 1) {
                var maquina = $("input[name=maquina]").val();
                var usuario = $("input[name=usuario_db]").val();
                var senha = $("input[name=senha_db]").val();

                $.ajax({
                  url: "<c:out value="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/instala/createdb"/>",
                  type: "POST",
                  data: { maquina : maquina, usuario_db: usuario, senha_db: senha }
                }).done(function(data){
                    if(data === "yes")
                        $wizard.wizard('next');
                });
            }
            else {
                var usuario = $("input[name=usuario]").val();
                var senha = $("input[name=senha1]").val();
                var pnome = $("input[name=primeiroNome]").val();
                var unome = $("input[name=ultimoNome]").val();

                $.ajax({
                      url: "<c:out value="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/instala/createuser"/>",
                      type: "POST",
                      data: { usuario : usuario, senha1: senha, primeiroNome: pnome, ultimoNome: unome }
                }).done(function(data) {
                    if(data === "yes")
                        $wizard.wizard('next');
                });
            }
        });

        $btnFinish.on("click", function() {
            location.href="<c:out value="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/acesso/login"/>";
        });

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using Bootstrap, just take advantage of the standard tab behavior to make your wizard.  Update your html like this:

```
<div id="pad-wrapper">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12 col-xs-12">
                    <div id="fuelux-wizard" class="wizard row">
                        <ul class="nav nav-pills wizard-steps">
                            <li class="active">
                                <a href="#step1" data-toggle="tab" >
                                <span class="step">1</span>
                                <span class="title">Banco de dados</span>
                                </a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#step2" data-toggle="tab" >
                                <span class="step">2</span>
                                <span class="title">Dados do administrador</span>
                                </a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#step3" data-toggle="tab">
                                <span class="step">3</span>
                                <span class="title">Conclus&atilde;o</span>
                                </a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>                            
                    </div>
                    <div class="step-content tab-content">

                        <div class="step-pane tab-pane active" id="step1">
                            <div class="row form-wrapper">
                                <div class="col-md-8">
                                    <form id="target" method="post" action="">
                                        <div class="field-box">
                                            <label>M&aacute;quina (IP):</label>
                                            <input class="form-control" type="text" name="maquina" />
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="field-box">
                                            <label>Usu&aacute;rio:</label>
                                            <input class="form-control" type="text" name="usuario_db" />
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="field-box">
                                            <label>Senha:</label>
                                            <input class="form-control" type="text" name="senha_db" />
                                        </div>
                                    </form>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="step-pane tab-pane" id="step2">
                            <div class="row form-wrapper">
                                <div class="col-md-8">
                                    <form id="target2" method="post" action="">
                                        <div class="field-box">
                                            <label>Usu&aacute;rio:</label>
                                            <input class="form-control" type="text" name="usuario" />
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="field-box">
                                            <label>Digite uma senha:</label>
                                            <input class="form-control" type="password" name="senha1" />
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="field-box">
                                            <label>Repita a senha:</label>
                                            <input class="form-control" type="password" name="senha2" />
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="field-box">
                                            <label>E-mail:</label>
                                            <input class="form-control" type="text" name="email" />
                                        </div>
                                    </form>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="step-pane tab-pane" id="step3">
                            <div class="row form-wrapper payment-info">
                                <div class="col-md-8">
                                    O sistema foi configurado com sucesso! Agora voc&ecirc; pode efetuar seu login e come&ccedil;ar a usa-lo.
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                    </div>

                    <div class="wizard-actions">
                        <button type="button" disabled class="btn-glow primary btn-prev"> 
                            <i class="icon-chevron-left"></i> Anterior
                        </button>
                        <button class="btn-glow primary btn-next" data-last="Finish">
                            Pr&otilde;ximo <i class="icon-chevron-right"></i>
                        </button>
                        <button type="button" onclick="" class="btn-glow success btn-finish">
                            Fa&ccedil;a login no sistema!
                        </button>
                    </div>

                    <div class="alert alert-danger" id="result">
                        <i class="icon-remove-sign"></i>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Now add some javascript to handle the navigation:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    var fnprocessform = function (targetform) {
        if (targetform.attr('id') === 'target') {
            //do your validation before you move to the next so you can show errors if needed 
            alert('validating form 1');
            //if the form is validated move to the next step
            var nextstep = $('.wizard-steps').find('.active').next();
            nextstep.find('a').tab('show');
            //then submit the form via ajax
            //to make sure that the behavior you expect happens 
            //when you process the form, you probably want to send back an id of the newly created record
            //so that if someone clicks back and then next again you don't create two records
            //instead you read the id and update the record  
        }
        if (targetform.attr('id') === 'target2') {
            //same comments as above
            alert('validating form 2');
            var nextstep = $('.wizard-steps').find('.active').next();
            nextstep.find('a').tab('show');
        }
    }
    $('.wizard-actions .btn-next').on('click', function() {
        var formtosubmit = $('.tab-pane.active').find('form');
        fnprocessform(formtosubmit);    
    });

    $('.wizard-actions .btn-prev').on('click', function() {
        var prevstep = $('.wizard-steps').find('.active').prev();
        prevstep.find('a').tab('show');
    });

    $('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('shown.bs.tab', function (e) {
        if ($('.wizard-steps').find('.active').is(':first-child')) { 
            $('.wizard-actions .btn-prev').prop('disabled', true);
        } else {
            $('.wizard-actions .btn-prev').prop('disabled', false);
        }
        if ($('.wizard-steps').find('.active').is(':last-child')) { 
            $('.wizard-actions .btn-next').prop('disabled', true);
        } else {
            $('.wizard-actions .btn-next').prop('disabled', false);
        }

    })

 });
```

To finish this up, you'll need to add some nice styling, write a click event handler for the nav-pills to prevent them from causing the tabs to show and you need to handle all of your validation and form processing, but this should really get you going.  You can make it even cooler by adding a progress bar using the built in progress bars in Bootstrap.

Comment: Ok, I just modify my jquery code to include this function (that's the current code: https://github.com/klebermo/webapp_horario_livre/blob/master/WebContent/WEB-INF/jsp/instala/index.jsp), and no action is triggered (even the alert). I try see if exists some message in the console, but nothing is displayed too.